# A question regarding the finiteness of the degree of a field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be transcendental and $y$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Let $F$ be an algebraic Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of infinite degree and let $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$ be the algebraic numbers.

Then is $F(y) \cap \mathbb{Q}^{al}$ of finite degree over $F \cap \mathbb{Q}^{al}$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\,p(y)=0\,$ for some $\,0\neq p(t)\in\Bbb Q(x)[t]\,$

You're asking whether

$$[F(y)\cap\Bbb Q^{al}\,:\,F\cap\Bbb Q^{al}]<\infty\;\;?$$

I think it is since $\,y\,$ is a root of the non-zero polynomial

$$p(t)\in\Bbb Q[x](t)\le L[t] $$

and since any other element in $\,F(y)\cap\Bbb Q^{ab}\,$ is algebraic over $\,\Bbb Q\,$ and thus over $\,L\,$ ...

I am not sure though what's the role of the  extension $\,F/\Bbb Q(x)\,$  being **Galois**, so perhaps I'm overseeing something. Check this.

Comment: Thank you. The Galois condition might be redundant. However, could you please add a couple more details, I still don't understand your proof?

Comment: This is my idea, @Steve : what are the elements of $\,F(y)\cap\Bbb Q^{ab}\,$ ? They are the *algebraic* elements in the field $\,F(y)\,$ , so each of these elements, say $\,w\,$,  is a root of some zero $\,p(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]\,$ . Since clearly $\,\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q(x)\subset F\,$ *and also* $\,\Bbb Q\le\Bbb Q^{ab}\,$ , we have that in fact $\,p(x)\in \left(F\cap\Bbb Q^{ab}\right)[x]\,$ and thus $\,w\,$ is algebraic over $\,F\cap\Bbb Q^{ab}\,$ ...

Comment: I presume you mean $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$ and not $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$? Also you meant $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x](t)$ as earlier? I still don't see how this makes this degree finite though?

Comment: Yes, of course: it is $\,\Bbb Q^{al}\,$ all the time (also, the abelianization of $\,\Bbb Q\,$ is pretty boring...)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I can't see how to get anywhere with your hint, could you please expand a little?